# Javascript Regexp Search and Replace

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I use javascript regexp to do a case insensitive, global search and replace on a string with the following pattern:

`[media id="5"]` or `[Media id=5]`

and replace entirely with:

```
http://someurl/?somevar=THE_ID_FROM_THE_PATTERN
```

So basically, something like this:

```
var mystring = '<img src="[media id=5]" />';
```

Should be converted to:

```
var newstring = '<img src="http://someurl/?somevar=5" />';
```

Comment: Is the whole string HTML content?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to capture the number, using parentheses, and add it back in with $1 when you replace. Also, based on your example, it should be case insensitive (//i) and the quotation marks are optional.

```
var mystring = '<img src="[media id=5]" />';
var re = /\[media id="?(\d+)"?\]/gi;
mystring.replace(re, "http://someurl/?somevar=$1");
```

Comment: yeah, the biggest issue i was having is with the optional question marks.  thanks a bunch!

Comment: how about if there are multiple [media id=X] tags in the string?  would i just need to add "g" to the following statement: var re = /\[media id="?(\d+)"?\]/ig;

Comment: Yes, but $1 is the first match so you'd have to adjust the replacement string somehow.

Comment: Actually, I just ran the code and it looks like it works with the global flag.

Answer (score 1):

`var regexp=/\[media id="5"\]/gi;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var mystring = '<img src="[media id=5]" />';
mystring.replace(/\[media id=5\]/gi, 'http://someurl/?somevar=5').toString();
```

AND/OR

```
var mystring = '<img src="[media id=\"5\"]" />';
mystring.replace(/\[media id=\"5\"\]/gi, 'http://someurl/?somevar=5').toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way, I think, would be something like this:

```
var regexp = /\[[mM]edia\ id\=\"\d+\"\]/g;
var mystring = '<img src="[media id=5]" />';
var newstring = mystring.replace(regexp, "http://someurl/?somevar=$1");
```

Comment: I guess I'm missing something - why not?

Comment: @AleksG because the quote characters in `regexp` are not optional. Tack on a question mark to them to allow 0 or 1 occurrence.