# Quoting regex literals in javascript? Why not?

Tags: javascript, regex, string-literals

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6751356/385571) to a question, and lots of other places, I see unquoted strings in javascript.

For example:

```
var re = /\[media id="?(\d+)"?\]/gi;
```

Why shouldn't it instead be:

```
var re = '/\[media id="?(\d+)"?\]/gi';
```

Is it some kind of special handling of regular expressions, or can any string be declared like that?

Comment: Thanks everybody. I've upvoted or accepted all answers. Upvoted the comment about w3schools as well. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it some kind of special handling of regular expressions?

Yes, regular expressions get special handling.  As [MDN points out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions), there is a built-in JavaScript regular expression type, with its own syntax for literals.

> or can any string be declared like that?

No.  Since regular expressions are objects and are not strings, if you tried to write a string with a regular expression literal you would get a regular expression object, not a string.

Answer (score 3):

```
var re = /\[media id="?(\d+)"?\]/gi;
```

is regex literal, not a string.

Answer (score 2):

it's only for regular expressions, not for strings.

Answer (score 2):

Because, in JavaScript, Regex is a built-in type, not a string-pattern that is passed to some parser like e.g. in C# or Java.

That means that when you write `var regex = /pattern/`, JavaScript automatically uses that literal as a regular expression pattern, making `regex` an object of the `RegExp` type.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is a much better reference than [w3fools](http://w3fools.com), w3schools has nothing to do with the real W3C, they just google bombed their way to the top.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware of that. My bad. Thanks for the hint, I will keep it in mind from now on.